# How do I use bound controls and InsertItemTemplate to insert data on a page and then forward to another page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a few simple asp.net pages forming sort of a wizard type interface. Each page has a form that uses an  with form fields that bind to LINQ entities on the back end. So I'm letting asp/linq do the work of inserting the data into the DB. One problem I'm running into is that the pages have to post back to themselves in order to insert the data correctly, but I want them to insert the data and then go to the next step in the wizard. Is it possible to do this someway using the base functionality of asp.net or do I have to do something else? Suggestions as to another way to do this are welcome.

sample code:

```
<form id="frmNewAccount" runat="server">
  <asp:FormView ID="frmUser" DataSourceID="srcUser" DefaultMode="Insert" runat="server">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" Text="Email Address (must already exist)" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail" runat="server"/>
      <asp:TextBox id="txtEmail" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind("EmailAddress") %>" Width="225"></asp:TextBox>                
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btnInsertUser" ImageUrl="Arrow.jpg" AlternateText="Submit" CommandName="Insert" runat="server" /> 
      </InsertItemTemplate>     
    </asp:FormView>       
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="srcUser" TypeName="User" DataObjectTypeName="App.Data.User" InsertMethod="Insert" runat="server"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I've ended up moving to asp.net mvc as it provides a lot more control and a paradigm I'm more familiar with. The model used in MVC is to post and then redirect using a RedirectToAction method. This is really what I was wanting to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **ASP.net Wizard control**

```
<asp:Wizard ID="AddEmployeeWizard" runat="server" CellPadding="5" Width="95%">
   <WizardSteps>
      <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Step 1" StepType="Start">
         ... Content for Step ...
      </asp:WizardStep>
      <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Step 2" StepType="Step">
         ... Content for Step ...
      </asp:WizardStep>
      ...
      <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Step 3" StepType="Finish">
         ... Content for Step ...
      </asp:WizardStep>
   </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```

Some links:

- [MSDN Magazine Cutting Edge Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/04/11/CuttingEdge/)
- [ASP.NET QuickStart Samples for the Wizard Control](http://www.asp.net/QuickStart/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/standard/wizard.aspx)
- [Create a Basic Wizard Control](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdb4eb30.aspx)
- [Create an Advanced Wizard Control](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5.aspx)
- [Wizard Control MSDN Reference Overview](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx)

Comment: This is a nice implementation for a simple wizard, but doesn't work (easily) for more dynamic and more complex wizards.